# How to display specific number from website?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to display a specific number taken from a website, but I can't find the way of doing it. For example, in a website where it has a countdown, I want to be able to read that number and display it in my app. Is that even possible?
Here's what I have in my java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://counter.onlineclock.net/");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"),8);
            textview.setText(reader.readLine());
            webs.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
}

catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to read the "counter" from that website, but I don't know how? Any solutions?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: that would be posible but if you  look into the source code of http://counter.onlineclock.net/ you can´t find the value of the counter, why no read from an .xml file? whats the purpose of this?

Comment: @Elenasys How I can read it from the .xml file? All I want is to display a number shown in a website in my app.

Comment: <div id="counter">3</div> When you do a post request the number from this div comes null, because its added using javascript. Basically you just can`t do this this way, you need access to the database where the value is being added. Or, you can use a webview (its sort of a browser widget) to show this site inside your app.